# Fermat primality test and Fermat pseudoprime

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

What is the difference between Fermat primality test and Fermat pseudoprime?Can anyone explain me how we use them ?

Comment: The "primality test" only really works one way:  if your candidate fails the test then we know it is composite.  If it passes then it may or may not be prime.  A Fermat pseudoprime, also called a Carmichael number, is one of the false positives.

Comment: pages 100,101 of D. Burton: Number theory 1st edition may be helpful.

Answer (score 3):

It is known that if $n$ is prime, then $a^{n-1} \equiv 1 \mod n$ for all $2 \le a \le n-1$. Reading this backwards, we get: if we can find some $a$ between $2$ and $n-1$ such that $a^{n-1} \not\equiv 1 \mod n$, then surely $n$ is not prime. If not, then $n$ is prime.

Therefore, you take the number $n$ to be tested and take $a=2$. If $2^{n-1} \not\equiv 1 \mod n$, then surely $n$ is not prime, and you stop. What happens if $2^{n-1} \equiv 1 \mod n$? In this case $n$ might or might not be a prime (it will be called a Fermat pseudoprime with base $2$) and you go to the next step.

If in the step above you obtained $2^{n-1} \equiv 1 \mod n$, then move on to $a=3$ and repeat the previous step as above. And so on, and so on, until you either find an $a$ with $a^{n-1} \not\equiv 1 \mod n$ (in which case $n$ will not be prime), or you exhaust the numbers between $2$ and $n-1$ and for each of them you get $a^{n-1} \equiv 1 \mod n$ (in which case $n$ will be prime).

Note that the above algorithm is very slow if $n$ happens to be a large prime.

Finally, a Fermat pseudoprime to base $a$ is a number $n$ such that $a^{n-1} \equiv 1 \mod n$, and yet is not prime.